# An ideal that contained in finitely many maximal ideals but all of its elements contained in infinitely many maximal ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra

Is it possible that an ideal I in an integral domain D is contained in only finitely many maximal ideals but each element of I is contained in infinitely many maximal ideals?
I am quit sure that it is possible but I need an example. If some one have in mind, please share.

Comment: Take $D=\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$, $I=(X,Y)$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But note that each maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ is of the form $(X-a,Y-b)$ for some a,b $\in$ $\mathbb{C}$. So it follows $(X,Y)$ is the only maximal ideal containing $X$. Similarly for $Y$. I need an example in which each element of ideal $I$  contained in infinitely many maximal ideals.

Comment: What about $(X,Y-1)$?

Comment: ooooh. Thanks a lot. I was blind at that point. Thank you so much